GitLab CI/CD variables: How to add environments on the group level?
I have a GitLab group with some projects in it that have environments configured. I want to add a GitLab group variable that is scoped to the test environment (GitLab Documentation).
In the GitLab project I have added a test environment:

In the GitLab project I can select the test environment:

However in the GitLab group there is no test environment to select:

How can I add my test environment to the group variables? This is a GitLab with Premium Subscription. I am Owner of the group.

Per https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/330974, group level environment variables seem to be a "premium" feature, maybe the feature is intentionally disabled?
However, it is not quite intuitive that to match multiple environments (of multiple projects) you need to create an "environment wildcard" matching the desired environment name(s) by typing the name, possible with an asterisk somewhere, and select the then-appearing "create wildcard" entry, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2874#note_585473711


Good point - yes it is intentionally disabled. The screenshots were from a free GitLab account, but the problem comes from a Premium Subscription. I've updated my question.

@mles It is interesting that you have any options at all, in my group there is not a single environment listed. However, as described in the answer, just TYPE the desired environment name into the search box, and then select the appearing "Create wildcard: " entry at the bottom. That should do the trick :-) I've inserted a screenshot to the post to probably illustrate it better.

That ... is indeed not very intuitive. The existing entries come from someone at my company that already solved that mystery.  Thanks for the hint!

Newer versions (at least 17.5, maybe lower) REQUIRE actual asterisk (*) at the end of the environment name to allow you to create a wildcard the same way it is displayed in the answers' screenshot.
